# map <leader>b<number> :b<number><cr>

Tags: vimrc, buffers

I am using a convenient macro to list my buffers: `map <leader>bb :buffers<cr>`

I am trying to come up with a way to then switch to the buffer of interest with `<leader>b<number>` but I haven't found how to catch a number in this map. I assume there should be some kind of delay involved in case I have a 2-digit number (highly unlikely), however, even single-digit number would suffice.

Comment: You may be interested in these gists: https://gist.github.com/romainl/047aca21e338df7ccf771f96858edb86#generalizing , https://gist.github.com/lacygoill/88437bcbbe90d1d2e2787695e1c1c6a9#chain-commands

Comment: FYI: `<c-^>`/`<c-6>` will jump to the alternative, `#`, buffer. With a count (`{count}<c-^>`) it is the same as `:b {count}`. See `:h CTRL-6`

Comment: Oh, thank you @PeterRincker! This is actually really nice and seems like a good alternative!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using a convenient macro

Just FYI, one can also do `:ls<CR>` to achieve the same result. So that one does not look like "a life saver" to me.

> a way to then switch to the buffer of interest

Again, that does not look so useful, as one can always do `:b[Number]<CR>` without any hassle. But let's figure out how we can create a "parameterized" mapping for this particular example.

First of all, normal mode commands in Vim can have a count, but it must be supplied *before* a command, not after it. So we aim to support `[Number]<leader>b` and not vice versa. The counter then will be available in a special variable `v:count` (or `v:count1`). Also, a user can press just `<leader>b` without any count supplied. And we must do something reasonable in this case, so let it be a "next buffer" command.

Next, we should make a command out of an expression (strings and numbers) and execute it. There are several ways to do so, but I think that `:h map-<expr>` is the best suit for this case.

So the mapping can be:

```
nnoremap <silent><expr><leader>b printf(":\<C-U>%s\n", v:count ? 'buffer' . v:count : 'bnext')
```

Now, `N<leader>b` works as `:buffer N`, and `<leader>b` works as `:bnext`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please elaborate on the mapping you came up with?  Specifically on the printf part.

Comment: I know about both :ls<CR> and :b[number]<cr>, I just don't like typing ":" - it's not convenient for me. :) Not trying to promote any life-saving shortcut here, just a personal preference.

Comment: @arbulgazar Here `printf()` is used merely to simplify string concatenation: the mapping produces a string which gets re-scanned because of `<expr>`. A possible alternative is to use `:execute`. BTW. to ease typing of `:` you can use `nnoremap ; :`

Answer (score 2):

For single-digit buffers, you can actually hardcode 9 mappings, one for each digit:

```
nnoremap <Leader>b1 :buffer 1<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b2 :buffer 2<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b3 :buffer 3<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b4 :buffer 4<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b5 :buffer 5<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b6 :buffer 6<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b7 :buffer 7<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b8 :buffer 8<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b9 :buffer 9<CR>
```

If you don't like the repetition, you could use a `:for` loop to produce these lines:

```
for i in range(1, 9)
    execute 'nnoremap <Leader>b'.i.
        \ ' :buffer '.i.'<CR>'
endfor
```

For the double-digit case, it can be tricky to do with a mapping. You can potentially use [`getchar()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getchar%28%29) to keep getting more characters and check whether they're valid digits. But you need a way to terminate the sequence, possibly by checking when you get a `<CR>` from `getchar()`, but that means the user will have to press an extra key to finish the sequence. (Though you could handle keys other than `<CR>` or digits by terminating the sequence and feeding them back with `feedkeys()`.)

Since an extra key is likely needed, you might consider using [`input()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#input%28%29) instead, in which case you can even allow completion on buffer names!

```
function! SwitchBuffer()
    " Start by listing existing buffers
    buffers
    let n = input('Switch to: ', '', 'buffer')
    execute 'buffer' n
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>bs :call SwitchBuffer()<CR>
```

You could use such a mapping in addition to the single-digit mappings, for cases where you want to use buffer names or two-digit buffer numbers. Also, listing them first as part of the command might be useful as well.